# Converting Syntax from sqllite to postgresql

Tags: sqlite, postgresql-9.3

I have a sqlLite database which contain in some field sql statement, this sql statement are needed to create some chart in an IOS Application.

Now I need to display this chart in a web application which use Postgresql
I need to find a script who convert from sqllite syntax to postgresql syntax 
things like printf, current date etc... 
I am asking if there is some ready to use script for this kind of conversion 
PS : I am using Symfony for the back-end so PHP

Example:

```
SELECT
    r.agent                                              AS gebiet,
    r.invoiceno                                          AS rechnung,
    r.infotext                                           AS auftrag,
    c.companyno                                          AS kundenr,
    c.companyname                                        AS kunde,
    r.itemno                                             AS artikelnr,
    r.itemtext                                           AS artikel,
    SUM(r.qty) || ' ' || r.unit                          AS menge,
    printf('%.2f', SUM(r.turnover) / SUM(r.qty))         AS preis,
    printf('%.2f', SUM(r.turnover)) || ' ' || r.currency AS gesamt,
    '2'                                                  AS 'sys_align9',
    '2'                                                  AS 'sys_align10',
    '2'                                                  AS 'sys_align11'
FROM
    invoices r
INNER JOIN
    company c
ON
    r.companyno = c.companyno
WHERE
    r.agent = ?
```

Comment: Note that Postgres 9.3 is scheduled to be [end-of-life](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) this month. You should really target an up-to-date version, e.g. 10

Comment: Someone might be able to help you, but we would need to see your SQLite code.  Please include this information.

Comment: I have somethings like that : select r.agent as gebiet, r.invoiceno as rechnung, r.infotext as auftrag, c.companyno as kundenr, c.companyname as kunde, r.itemno as artikelnr, r.itemtext as artikel, sum(r.qty) || ' ' || r.unit as menge, printf('%.2f', sum(r.turnover) / sum(r.qty)) as preis, printf('%.2f',sum(r.turnover)) || ' ' || r.currency as gesamt, '2' as 'sys_align9','2' as 'sys_align10','2' as 'sys_align11'  from invoices r inner join company c on r.companyno = c.companyno where r.agent = ?

Comment: Please provide the table structure, example data and output. Please edit your question for this and do not put this into the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't know SQLite ;)

The query structure itself looks good, but two things will not work with Postgres:

- I assume `printf()` formats the output to two decimals, so `to_char()` is probably what you are looking for
- identifiers need to be enclosed in double quotes, not single quotes. So `AS 'sys_align11'` should be `AS "sys_align11" but the quotes are not required to begin with.

```
SELECT
    r.agent                                              AS gebiet,
    r.invoiceno                                          AS rechnung,
    r.infotext                                           AS auftrag,
    c.companyno                                          AS kundenr,
    c.companyname                                        AS kunde,
    r.itemno                                             AS artikelnr,
    r.itemtext                                           AS artikel,
    SUM(r.qty) || ' ' || r.unit                          AS menge,
    to_char(SUM(r.turnover) / SUM(r.qty), '0.00')        AS preis,
    to_char(SUM(r.turnover),'0.00') || ' ' || r.currency AS gesamt,
    '2'                                                  AS sys_align9,
    '2'                                                  AS sys_align10,
    '2'                                                  AS sys_align11
FROM
    invoices r
INNER JOIN
    company c
ON
    r.companyno = c.companyno
WHERE
    r.agent = ?
```

If `turnover` is an `integer` (or `bigin`) you need to cast it to numeric, otherwise the division is done as an integer division, e.g. `SUM(r.turnover)::numeric`

As you are using an aggregat function you will need some kind of `group by` in Postgres - otherwise the result wouldn't be deterministic.

If `invoiceno` is the primary key of the `invoices` table, a `group by r.invoiceno'  should be enough.